# Non marking field with @Transient and with spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

Tags: spring, hibernate

What will be behavior/impact on application

if I make do not mark a field with @Transient annotation and also setting property  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none?

Example :
Entity: Product.java [id, name, amount, discount]
Field discount is calculated field by some business logic in same class.

This is mapped to table :
product_master (id, nm, amt)
My question is:

What will happen if I don't mark property discount with @Transient annotation and try to do CRUD operations on product entity.

Having said that spring property
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none.

Answer (score 0):

Your CRUD will fail if you don't mark `discount` as @Transient

If you don't mark `discount` as `@Transient`, JPA will include this field in all queries to the database. If you try to do an INSERT into your table, `discount` field will be included in your create query and it will be fail because `discount` field does not exist in your database table.

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto has nothing to do with @Transient